# Is assembly code cross-platform?

Tags: assembly, machine-code

```
0x042444FF; /* inc dword ptr [esp+4] */
```

`0x042444FF` is the machine code,while `inc dword ptr [esp+4]` is the assembly code, I know 
machine code is NOT cross-platform,as it depends on many factors.

What about assembly code, does it depends on CPU ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assembly code is not cross platform.

Usually there is a very direct mapping between machine instructions and assembly instructions so the assembly code depends on the architecture.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language):

> An assembly language is a low-level programming language for computers, microprocessors, microcontrollers, and other integrated circuits. It implements a symbolic representation of the binary machine codes and other constants needed to program a particular CPU architecture. This representation is usually defined by the hardware manufacturer, and is based on mnemonics that symbolize processing steps (instructions), processor registers, memory locations, and other language features. **An assembly language is thus specific to a certain physical (or virtual) computer architecture**. This is in contrast to most high-level languages, which are ideally portable.

Comment: Its also not cross OS for the most part, as you are depending on calling conventions, interupt codes etc. which are set by the OS.

Comment: Is `__cdecl` calling conversion windows only?

Answer (score 2):

Assembly code is basically a worded form of the machine code; it is designed to make writing machine code a little more convenient and readable. There is pretty much a one-to-one mapping of the two, so one assembly statement is turned into its machine code equivalent. Macine code is CPU-dependent. Assembly is therefore, also CPU-dependent.